# How to parse new incoming message?

Tags: android, sqlite

Am developing an android application in which i have created "Server" database. In that database i have two tables i,e employee_table and attendance_table in that i hav not included my onReceive function and with that onReceive function i need to parse the new message and that message content should be store in employee table and attendance table so please me out to solve this issue..

Thanks in advance..

Here is my DbHelper.java :

```
package com.example.attendancesystem;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DATABASE_NAME="Server";
    public static final String EmployeeTable="employee_table";
    public static final String Name="name";
    public static final String Mobile_no="mobile";
    public static final String Id="id";

    public static final String AttendanceTable="attendance_table";
    public static final String Latitude="Lat";
    public static final String Longitude="Lan";
    public static final String Accuracy="Accry";
    public static final String Date="date";
    public static final String Time="time";



    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+EmployeeTable+" ("+Id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+Name+" TEXT, "+Mobile_no+" VARCHAR(13))";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

         CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+AttendanceTable+" ("+Latitude+" double precision, "+Longitude+" double precision, "+Accuracy+" double,"+Date+" date,"+Time+"time)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+EmployeeTable);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+AttendanceTable);

        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

Comment: you need to put reciver to get new incomining message..

Comment: ya... I dont know whether i need to create a new class or i pace a code in this class only or wat?? please help me...

Comment: Please help me along with code snippet...

Comment: you need to check some help from http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87